# Librosa Keras Python Neural Network Error: Batch End Is Slow Compared To Batch Update

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, librosa

I have recently attempted to perform an experiment whereby a neural network written in the Python IDE IDLE using Keras is used to analyse the GTZAN dataset of songs. I am attempting to vary the layers in order to see if there is any impact on performance. I am basing my experiment on a particular article detailing the basis of this project:

https://medium.com/@navdeepsingh_2336/identifying-the-genre-of-a-song-with-neural-networks-851db89c42f0

The program displayed in this experiment forms the program:

```
import librosa
import librosa.feature
import librosa.display
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

def display_mfcc(song):
    y, _ = librosa.load(song)
    mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
    librosa.display.specshow(mfcc, x_axis='time', y_axis='mel')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title(song)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


def extract_features_song(f):
    y, _ = librosa.load(f)

    mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y)
    mfcc /= np.amax(np.absolute(mfcc))

    return np.ndarray.flatten(mfcc)[:25000]

def generate_features_and_labels():
    all_features = []
    all_labels = []
    genres = ['blues', 'classical', 'country', 'disco', 'hiphop',
    'jazz', 'metal', 'pop', 'reggae', 'rock']

    for genre in genres:
        sound_files = glob.glob('genres/'+genre+'/*.au')
        print('Processing %d songs in %s genre...' % 
        (len(sound_files), genre))
        for f in sound_files:
            features = extract_features_song(f)
            all_features.append(features)
            all_labels.append(genre)

    label_uniq_ids, label_row_ids = np.unique(all_labels,   
    (len(sound_files), genre))
    label_row_ids = label_row_ids.astype(np.int32, copy=False)
    onehot_labels = to_categorical(label_row_ids, 
    len(label_uniq_ids))

    return np.stack(all_features), onehot_labels


features, labels = generate_features_and_labels()

print(np.shape(features))
print(np.shape(labels))

training_split = 0.8

alldata = np.column_stack((features, labels))

np.random.shuffle(alldata)
splitidx = int(len(alldata) * training_split)
train, test = alldata[:splitidx,:], alldata[splitidx:,:]

print(np.shape(train))
print(np.shape(test))

train_input = train[:,:-10]
train_labels = train[:,-10:]

test_input = test[:,:-10]
test_labels = test[:,-10:]

print(np.shape(train_input))
print(np.shape(train_labels))

model = Sequential([
    Dense(100, input_dim=np.shape(train_input)[1]),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(10),
    Activation('softmax'),
    ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

model.fit(train_input, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32,         
validation_split=0.2)

loss, acc = model.evaluate(test_input, test_labels, batch_size=32)

print("Done!")
print("Loss: %.4f, accuracy: %.4f" % (loss, acc))
```

Python began to print the expected response:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Processing 100 songs in blues genre...
Processing 100 songs in classical genre...
Processing 100 songs in country genre...
Processing 100 songs in disco genre...
Processing 100 songs in hiphop genre...
Processing 100 songs in jazz genre...
Processing 100 songs in metal genre...
Processing 100 songs in pop genre...
Processing 100 songs in reggae genre...
Processing 100 songs in rock genre...
(1000, 25000)
(1000, 10)
(800, 25010)
(200, 25010)
(800, 25000)
(800, 10)
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 100)               2500100   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1010      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 10)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 2,501,110
Trainable params: 2,501,110
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

None
    Train on 640 samples, validate on 160 samples
    Epoch 1/10

```
32/640 [>.............................] - ETA: 7s - loss: 2.3115 -     
acc: 0.0625
64/640 [==>...........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 3.3871 - 
acc: 0.1094
96/640 [===>..........................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 3.2331 - 
acc: 0.1562
128/640 [=====>........................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 2.9779 - 
acc: 0.1797
160/640 [======>.......................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 2.7778 - 
acc: 0.1938
192/640 [========>.....................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 2.6937 - 
acc: 0.2031
224/640 [=========>....................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 2.5870 - 
acc: 0.2232
256/640 [===========>..................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 2.5168 - 
acc: 0.2305
288/640 [============>.................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 2.5075 -   
acc: 0.2153
```

But this was interrupted by the periodic printing of additional epoch information and the error message:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 122
% delta_t_median)
UserWarning: Method on_batch_end() is slow compared to the batch update (0.102488). Check your callbacks.
```

I am unsure as to how to fix this problem. Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Don't confuse a warning with an error.

Comment: I understand that this message was a warning. However, it interferes with my visual interpretation of the error. How must one eliminate it? Thank you.